# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am new o Java, trying to create a simple login and registration page by connecting to mysql database. I followed this link

http://www.javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/

I have changed registration.jsp to

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String user = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB",
            "root", "password");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    //ResultSet rs;
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(first_name, last_name, email, uname, pass, regdate) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pwd + "', CURDATE())");
    if (i > 0) {
        //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
       // out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>
```

But, when I try to register I am getting this error

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:80)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4004)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2312)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Help me, what is causing the issue.

**Edit:** I can able to login using same username & password (root & password)

[image]

Comment: check login / password in your database

Comment: @N123 looks like username /or password is wrongly typed , can you please confirm first on it.

Comment: check if console login still works if you include `-h localhost` in command line

Comment: Sorry @Jan, Do you want me to type **-h localhost** in mysql command line?

Comment: yes - that would kind of emulate the hostname part where your login from java seems to fail. so go `mysql -u root -h localhost -p`

Comment: @Jan I can able to login with  **mysql -u root -h localhost -p**